# If $n,k\in\Bbb{N}$ and $\binom{n}{k}$ is a prime number, then $k = 1$ or $k = n−1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I need help prooving that if $n,k\in\Bbb{N}$ and $\binom{n}{k}$
is a prime number, then $k = 1$ or $k = n−1$.

Comment: Please, tell us what you have tried and specifically where did you stack. We are not obligate to answer your homework.

Comment: Well I tried four different ways to disprove the statement where I used (prime prime) (prime non-prime) (non-prime prime) and (non-prime non-prime). (7 5)=21  (7 4)= 35  (8 4)=70 (8 5)= 56. As you see I got all non-prime numbers.

Comment: If there is a way to prove my statement, could you at least give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use two facts about binomial coefficients.  The first fact is the fairly obvious observation that

$${n\choose1}={n\choose n-1}=n\quad\text{and}\quad{n\choose k}\gt n\quad\text{for }1\lt k\lt n-1$$

The second fact is a crucial divisibility property:

$$n\mid(n,k){n\choose k}\quad\text{for }0\lt k\lt n$$

[The inequality in the first fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198897) follows easily from the equality ${n\choose k}={n-k\over k}{n\choose k-1}$.  As for the second fact, imagine $n$ objects arranged in a circle, $k$ of which are black and the others white.  Any rotation of such an arrangement by $h$ places, with $0\le h\lt n/(n,k)$, gives a different arrangement.  This implies $n/(n,k)$ divides $n\choose k$, which means $n$ divides $(n,k){n\choose k}$.

Now assume that ${n\choose k}=p$ is prime.  Then the second fact implies $(n,k)p=nm$ for some $m$.  But $0\lt k\lt n$ implies $(n,k)\lt n$, so $nm=(n,k)p\lt np$, which implies $m\lt p$, which in turn implies $p\not\mid m$, which in turn implies $p\mid n$, which implies $n\ge p$.  Invoking now the first fact, we have $p={n\choose k}\ge n\ge p$, so that we must have $n=p={n\choose k}$, and therefore $k=1$ or $n-1$.

Comment: not clear about your argument on $n$ dividing $(n,k){n \choose k}$. Can u pls clarify ? Although since ${n \choose k}>n$ and if ${n \choose k } = p$ is  a prime and since ${n \choose k}$ cannot have a prime factor $>n$, this means ${n \choose k}$ prime is impossible whenever ${n \choose k}>n$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: I agree with your simpler proof, @Balajisb. Why not edit it as an answer?

Comment: @AnneBauval added the answer. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

By cyclically shifting the choice of $k$ elements from $n$ elements and adding $1$ more choice of $k$ elements from $n$ elements which is possible iff $k \neq 1,n-1$, we get, $${n \choose k} > n, for \ k \neq 1,n-1$$

1. ${n \choose k}$ cannot have prime factors $>n$.
2. ${n \choose k} = p$ prime according to hypothesis.
3. ${n \choose k} > n$ for $k \neq 1,n-1$ according to above argument.

Points 1,2,3 are inconsistent for $k \neq 1,n-1$. Hence the hypothesis in point 2) that ${n \choose k}$ is prime is not possible unless $k = 1 \ or \ n-1$.

Answer (score -1):

Try to think about when $$\binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
is a prime number.

What happen when $k\notin\{1,n-1\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, what happens then? If the claim to be proved is true, there should at least two prime factors in the numerator that are not canceled out by the denominator, but it doesn't seem obvious that this is the case.