# Proof by contradiction regarding binomial coefficients and primes

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

PROBLEM: provide a proof by contradiction of the following statement

"If $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\binom{n}{k}$ is a prime number, then $k=1$ or $k=n-1$."

My reasoning is shown below.

The statement can be translated in formal logic as shown below

P: $\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N},  (\binom{n}{k}$ is prime) $\Rightarrow  (k=1 \wedge k=n-1)$

The negation is

not P: $\exists  n,k \in \mathbb{N}, (\binom{n}{k}$ is prime)$ \wedge (k\neq1) \wedge (k\neq n-1)$

The goal is to prove that not P leads to a contradiction. Let's consider some trivial cases to narrow down the problem.

Case $k=n \rightarrow \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n}=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $1$ is not prime, so we have a contradiction.

Case $k>n \rightarrow \binom{n}{k}=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but $0$ is not prime, so we have a contradiction.

So from $(k\neq1) \wedge (k\neq n-1)$ above and from these two cases we conclude that $1<k<n-1$, or equivalently $2\leq k \leq n-2$. So our statement not P becomes

not P: $\exists  n,k \in \mathbb{N}, (\binom{n}{k}$ is prime)$ \wedge (2\leq k \leq n-2)$

and expanding the definition of binomial coefficient, and calling $p$ a prime

not P: $\exists  n,k \in \mathbb{N}, 2\leq k \leq n-2, \frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1) }{k!}=p$

any ideas to continue?

EDIT: this post ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005673/if-n-k-in-bbbn-and-binomnk-is-a-prime-number-then-k-1-or-k-n%E2%88%92)) provides a direct proof, but I am looking for a proof by contradiction, so my post is not a duplicate.

Comment: The big thing about primes is that they don't have proper factors besides 1. A contradiction involving primes is usually that the prime must have a proper factor $>1$. Look at your equation...

Comment: Though you claim to be looking for a proof by contradiction (why, btw?), the linked post *is* essentially a duplicate. Your "translation in formal logic" only complicates the reasoning.

Comment: Thanks Anne, if you see any mistake in my reasoning please let me know. Also, could you help me to continue the proof?

Comment: (I was not notified. I discover your comment just now.) No mistake. Just look at the duplicate to end the proof.